# Excel Conditionalis Statement to calculate the percentage value

Tags: excel-formula

I have the few groups of products, I want to check if the Artical id start with"75" then i have to apply the 20% discount from the PriceNetto. if the Artikal Id strt with another number I have to apply the 10% discount. how can I do this in excel 2013?

Thanks in advance, please refer the attachment

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to work from an image, but something like:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,2)=75,C2*0.8,"")
```

You can put the 80% ie 0.8 in a separate cell (I have put G2) so it is easy to edit so:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,2)=75,C2*G2,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

If Artical ID starts at A2 going down, and PriceNetto starts at B2 going down, then you can enter the following formula at C2:

```
=B2*IF(LEFT(A2,2)=75,0.8,0.9)
```